# omxplayer - how to force elapsed-time:total-time display during pause

Tags: display, omxplayer

I want videos played via **omxplayer** to display `elapsed-time:total-time` on screen when paused, and then go back to just showing the video when playing.

I have "searched" until I'm blue in the fingers and cannot find anything definitive.  I *have* managed to get the time display on-screen to "work" after fiddling with stuff in /boot, but I'm not sure if it was that, part of an "apt upgrade", or something else that restored the feature I've come to love.

I also cannot find any documentation on this anywhere.  One thing I've noticed is that this feature seems to have vanished from ALL of my Raspberry Pi's omxplayers sometime around two years ago.

I found one reference to the on-screen time elapsed display in a function in the code on GitHub, but it wasn't well documented, and I'm not sure I can find even that again.  I'd sure like to know how to turn on "display elapsed time and the total time of the video when paused" for omxplayer.

Comment: This *may* have something to do with enabling "fkms" in /boot/config.txt.  i.e.:  [pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

Answer (score 0):

NO!  THIS IS NOT THE SOLUTION!  Aaaargh!!  How can I be the ONLY person in the entire planet who uses OMX player and misses time displayed during pause??  :-(

I think that I have finally solved this, just moments after having given up and asked.  :-p

Apparently enabling "fkms" in /boot/config.txt.  i.e.:

```
[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
```

BREAKS ON SCREEN TIME DISPLAY!
I commented out those lines, and added a gpu_mem=128 to the end of that file, rebooted, and now I have on-screen time-elapsed:total-time displaying during pause!  I hope this helps someone else, probably me when I forget again, in the future.  Whew!  FWIW, this is on a Raspberry Pi 3.  Now, to try to solve the same problem as showing up on Raspberry Pi 4 machines too.  (same solution?)